Moment of inertia doubt about rod rotating about an axis in two different ways

Does the moment of inertia in both the cases remain same or are they different about the axis shown in figure
In left one, the rod is purely rotating about the axis but in the right one the rod is rotating about the axis and also rotating about its centre of mass simultaneously

The example on the left is not a rigid body about the axis shown and so does not have a MOI.

If I understand your drawing correctly, you've got a rod rotating about an axis through the centre of mass in the first case, and about an axis through one of its ends in the second case?
If so, then the MOI are $\frac{1}{12} ML^2$ and $\frac{1}{3} ML^2$ respectively.
If you meant something else, then please clarify.

No it seems that one rod keeps it's orientation while rotating but keeps an end towards the axis in the second
